# How to create function that returns all combinations of this list in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion

I have this kind of list:

```
[['I'],['want','love','like'],['cat',dog]]
```

and I want to create a function that can return all combinations of words in the lists like this:

```
[['I'],['want'],['cat']]
[['I'],['love'],['cat']]
[['I'],['like'],['cat']]
[['I'],['want'],['dog']]
[['I'],['love'],['dog']]
[['I'],['like'],['dog']]
```

PS: The function must work with any `n` words

Comment: You can refer to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists/33425736

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import itertools
for k in itertools.product(*lst):
    print(k)
```

Comment: thanks it works. You save my time.

Comment: @TanakornTaweepoka You are welcome. You can also try `print(' '.join(k))` (or `s = ' '.join(k)`) to get a string with all parts of the sentence "glues" together into a single string.